# Batch file suggestions

Tags: batch-file, scripting, automation

I am writing a batch file that will run my automation scripts. However, I wish to ask user permission to proceed after completion of every test? What could be done in this case? Also I  am trying to put meaningful command line statements in the file but unable to do so.. Below is my batch file.

```
cd C:\Automation

ruby may11.rb

@ECHO OFF PAUSE

ruby multiYear.rb

@ECHO OFF PAUSE

ruby testcase2_mktAdjustment.rb

:choice
@ECHO OFF  set /P c=Do you want to exit [y/n]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :optA
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :optB
goto :choice

:optA

pause 
exit

:optB
cmd /k
```

Also once the script is completed, it goes into infinite loop for options A & B when opted for 'No' to quit.

Please help.

Abhishek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd C:\Automation

ruby may11.rb

PAUSE

ruby multiYear.rb

PAUSE

ruby testcase2_mktAdjustment.rb

:select
set /P c=Do you want to exit [y/n]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto optA
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto optB
goto select

:optA

pause 
exit

:optB
:: no idea what you want to do here...
```

The `@echo off` command turns `echo`ing of the commands off. The `@` actually turns off `echo` for the current command, so that `ECHO OFF` doesn't appear.

Using it in the manner you were will simply reproduce the line on-screen as a message, nothing more. It won't `pause` or `set` anything, just show the line after the keyword `echo`.

I've changed a few other things.

:choice becomes :select because `choice` is a batch keyword, best avoided as labels.

the colon in a `goto` is not required and best omitted.

There's no indication what you want to do with a `n` input.

Your `set` command was not being executed. `c` was not being set, so it failed both `if` tests and simply entered an infinite loop.

Comment: thank you for your inputs, it worked for me. I wanted 'n' input to allow user to remain in command prompt giving access to current directory.

Answer (score 1):

One very simple way to put a prompt to continue is to use the following statements:

```
@echo Press Ctrl+C to quit now or
@pause
```

This will output the following:

```
Press Ctrl+C to quit now or 
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Pressing Ctrl+C will ask the user to confirm cancelling the batch file by stating

```
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Only a <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd> will work.  Press any other key and it will just ask again.

Comment: Press Ctrl+C to quit now or
pause worked but after execution of last script when issued command ctrl+c , it again goes into infinite loop.

Comment: My guess is it's the `cmd /k` statement.  I'm not sure what that is for.  Can you remove that and see if it fixes the problem?